# Detect broswer language for automatic localization

Tags: grails

How can I detect the language of the browser and automatically display the correctly localized version of my grails website depending on that value.

Comment: What's your question actually? It looks like there's something missing...

Comment: if the website is viewed by a browser with russian language (as primary language) then russian localization is turned on automatically? In all other cases English localization is turned on by default.

Comment: I edited the question to what I think it meant. Feel free to rollback my change.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/10.%20Internationalization.html),

> By default the user locale is detected from the incoming
>   Accept-Language header. However, you can provide users the capability
>   to switch locales by simply passing a parameter called **lang** to Grails
>   as a request parameter:
>
> ```
> /book/list?lang=es
> ```
>
> Grails will automatically switch the user locale and store it in a
>   cookie so subsequent requests will have the new header.

Comment: Thanks for your useful suggestion but i think that it is related to localeResolver